# bootstrap jquery: adding async

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous

To improve the page speed, Google advises to add "async" to JavaScript. So I've changed the link for the the jqueryfiles into:

It improves the pagespeed indeed, but the "hamburger"menu doesn't work on phones. The menu doensn't open anymore.
Moving the jquery-link form the head to body section doesn't have any effect.

Anybody here who has a solution?

Comment: please put an code example of your script tags. And maybe the specific code für your menu

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use async, your browser will not wait for your server call to be completed, instead it will hit call to server and continue executing rest of the functions.

this is where you DOM will be ready before you get response from server and those functions that are dependent on server response will not work.

to make it work, put your function which are dependent on server call into success, done response of you ajax.